# Solve equation in Java with modulo

Tags: java, algorithm, math, equation

I need to solve this equation in my Java app:

```
(1080 * j + 1) modulo 7 = 0
```

Is there some more safe way how to get this value instead of this code? I am not much happy with `while` loop condition.

```
    int j = 1;
    int e = 7;
    boolean found = false;
    double r = 0;

    while (!found) {
        r = (1080 * j + 1);
        found = r % e == 0;
        j++;
    }

    int t = (int) (r / e);
```

Comment: @splrs - yes, but I am not happy because maybe-infinitive loop.

Comment: It's not maybe infinitive, value of (1080*j+1)%7 is periodic with period not bigger than 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your solution significantly using maths. You need to find a number that multiplied by 1080 will given a remainder 6 modulo 7 (because after adding 1 it should be divisible by 7). Now 1080 gives remainder 2 modulo 7. Thus you need to find number that multiplied by 2 gives 6 modulo 7. Lets check all 7 possible remainders:

```
0 * 2 = 0 (modulo 7)
1 * 2 = 2 (modulo 7)
2 * 2 = 4 (modulo 7)
3 * 2 = 6 (modulo 7)
4 * 2 = 1 (modulo 7)
5 * 2 = 3 (modulo 7)
6 * 2 = 5 (modulo 7)
```

So the only solutions to your problem are the numbers giving `remainder 3 (modulo 7)` and all such numbers are solutions of the equation.

Comment: He might need to write this algorithm in a "longer" fashion due to his assignment requirement, so your shortcut might be problematic for him to use

Comment: @nrathaus true but the question is `is there a more safe way`. My solution is both faster and safer I believe.

Comment: Ok, though it looks like its a homework assignment, you don't want him to get an F because he answered it differently :)

Comment: @nrathaus - this code is not a homework, it's part of my implementation of RSA algorithm for testing purposes :)

Comment: Very nice... if you added the implementation as well it would be the answer OP is looking for. E.g. 3+7X where X is any positive integer results in a J that works. Js that work (3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, 45...etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(1080*j + 1)% 7 =((1080*j)%7 + 1%7 )%7
```

And `(1080*j)%7 = ((1080%7)*(j%7))%7 = (2*(j%7))% 7`

And actually, j only need to run from 0 to 6, as you can clearly see that this is a periodic cycle, which help you to avoid infinite loop, as well as any number (not necessary 7)

Answer (score 0):

`(1080*j+1) mod 7 = 0 => 1080*j = 1 (mod 7)`. So you can use `For` loop from `0` to `6` like this :

```
int j;
for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    if((1080*i) % 7==1) {
         j=i; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to simplify the equation :-

> (1080*j + 1)mod 7 = 0
>
> (1080*j)mod7 = 6
>
> by multiplication theorem of modular arithmetic : -
>
> (a*b)%k  = (a%k * b%k)%k   hence (1080*j)%7 = (1080%7 * j%7)
>
> 1080%7 = 2
>
> hence (1080*j)%7 = (2* j%7)%7 = 6
>
> Now j%7 could have values (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
>
> now of all possible values j%7 = 3  would give (2*3)%7 = 6
>
> j%7 = 3
>
> therefore j = k*7 + 3 is solution to equation where k is any whole
>   number